# Boolean operators

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to figure out if a year is a leap year or not
I wrote this code, but I don't understand why it work, when I input 1996 it's "true" and when I enter 1700 it's "false" but why doesn't the "and" function returns false on 1996? shouldn't it check the left side and return a "false" ? ps. I work with anaconda3.2020-02:

```
bool(((x%100 == 0) * x%400 == 0) and x%4 == 0 )
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect the `*` to do here? Did you try checking the results for sub-expressions to see if they behave like you want? For example, is the result of `((x%100 == 0) * x%400 == 0)` what you expect it to be?

Comment: I new to programing in general.
I tried checking and the result is not what I expect, I kind of got frustrated with it and just tried anything and somehow it worked.
what I expected it to do is check if the year ends with 00 and if so also check if it divides by 400 without a remainder.
So if the first half ( x%100 == 0) is true then it would mean a "1" so I would like to check it and if not the in would yield a "0" and I would ignore the division by 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `*` at all. The expression you want is

```py
x % 400 == 0 or (x % 100 != 0 and x % 4 == 0)
```

(`bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True == 1`, so `and` is *sort of* like `and`, but `True * True` is `1`, not `True`, and `True + True` is `2`, not `True` or even `1`. Don't use arithmetic with Boolean values.)

Comment: Yes this line is exactly what I should have written, I'm new to coding in general.
I used the * because I thought that if x%100 == 0 would yield a 0 the no the I wouldn't need to check the next part which is x%400 == 0 because it would multiply it by 0 giving me a zero .
basically I wanted to order my operation.